# Google advanced boolean query

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I am trying to create an advanced boolean query that searches for derogatory content on the web, for use in back-grounding. I have tried "AROUND" in Google and "near:" in Bing; neither seems to work. Why don't they work? Is there a better way?

The query would be something like:

Firstname [and within 2 words] Lastname AND Lastname [and within 15 words] accus* OR appeal OR arraign* OR arrest* OR controvers* OR convict* OR scam* OR unlawful OR threat* OR scam* OR "no confidence" OR scandal* OR felon* OR lawsuit OR unethical [etc, other derogatory keywords]

Answer (score 0):

"Why don't they work?"

Many of the big search engines these days don't apply boolean constraints as a strict requirement of the search. Instead, they're used as 'hints', which is to say that the pages that conform are given higher scores, but you'll also see pages that don't conform if they seem to be a closer match to the terms. The AROUND function is handled in the same way (and it worked when I tried it).

"Is there a better way?"

You may find something that meets your requirements here:
http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2065129/Search-Features-Chart

Though it may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks, bdean20. Sorry it took me so long to notice your response. The Search Features Chart is a good find, but again, the "near" functions it lists don't seem to work. Eg, Lycos is one of the search engines that supposedly has a "near" boolean function. When I search ("testing search") in quotations in Lycos, the second result returned is "Testing Search - philosophe"; when I enter the search ("testing search" NEAR philosophe), the search engine returns no results. Why not? Are there any search engines that do apply boolean constraints as a strict requirement of the search? If not, why not?